# pandas group by with isin statement return index true/false

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
          balance
currency 
JPY       2342
USD       33245
BTC       23424
ETH       19080
CNY       89678
```

The following code return the sum from the dataframe within only 2 categories, true and false:

```
bal = df.groupby(~user_bal.index.isin(['BTC', 'ETH'])).sum()
```

While the expected output is as follow where [JPY,USD,CNY] have been summed under one index named JPY:

```
          balance
currency 
JPY       125265
BTC       23424
ETH       19080
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `where` first and then `groupby` + `sum`:

```
groups=df.index.where(df.index.isin(['BTC', 'ETH']),'JPY')
df.groupby(groups).sum()
```

Output:

```
          balance
currency         
BTC         23424
ETH         19080
JPY        125265
```

---

**Details**:
Mask and replace with `where`+`isin` to change the values that are not in the list with `'JPY'`:

```
groups=df.index.where(df.index.isin(['BTC', 'ETH']),'JPY')
print(groups)
>>>Index(['JPY', 'JPY', 'BTC', 'ETH', 'JPY'], dtype='object', name='currency')
```

Then group by `groups` and sum.